# Cannot play recorded video in Android

Tags: android, video, mp4, android-mediarecorder, android-camera2

I want to play a video using a `mediaPlayer` taken by my own app in Android.

I setup the `mediaPlayer` this way:

```
private void setUpMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (null == activity) {
        return;
    }
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    if (mNextVideoAbsolutePath == null || mNextVideoAbsolutePath.isEmpty()) {
        mNextVideoAbsolutePath = getVideoFilePath();
    }
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mNextVideoAbsolutePath);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    switch (mSensorOrientation) {
        case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT_DEGREES:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            break;
        case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_DEGREES:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            break;
    }
    mMediaRecorder.prepare();
}

private void stopRecordingVideo() {
    mMediaRecorder.stop();
    mMediaRecorder.reset();
}

return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
            + time + ".mp4"; // path, where the video should be stored
```

And when I want to play the taken video I get the following error: `This video cannot be played`.
Do you know why that isn't working? I've also tried the `Android-camera2video` example and also there the code isn't working.

Comment: Are you sure that the video is not corrupt (Have you alerady tested it with vlc player)? Are you sure that your mobile device supportsthe video codec H264 (have you tested it with a video from Internet)?

Comment: Hmm could the name of the video be the problem? If I name my video `video.mp4` it's working

Comment: It seems, some apps having thier own rules for file names

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks like your are using time + ".mp4" as the name.

Based on the error and the behaviour it is most likely that 'time' contains some characters which are either confusing the path resolution (e.g. /) or are confusing the file extensions somehow, maybe by adding and extra '.' for example.

If you want to append the date to your file name then you can use a formatter to get it into a 'safe' format for example:

```js
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");
```